# Как реализовать поисковое ядро для самописного сайта на php

Tags: php, mysql

Cайт на базе mysql.
Как реализовать поисковое ядро для самописного сайта на php?
Буду признателен любому ответу, хотя бы в каком направлении двигаться. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Пишем собственное поисковое ядро." [Часть 1](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub_id=37&id=1264) , [Часть 2](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub_id=37&id=1265) Я не считаю это идеальным решением, но как старт для понимания сойдёт. Там же можно почитать статью "Поисковая оптимизация сайта":  Части [-1-](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub_id=28&id=441), [-2-](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub_id=28&id=514), [-3-](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub_id=28&id=515), [-4-](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub_id=28&id=517)

Comment: Спасибо, буду смотреть) еще sphinx надо глянуть )

Answer (score 2):

Если ваш интерес более академический нежели практический - читайте статьи, преложенные Deonis'ом - делайте свой, если наоборот, тогда советую обратить внимание на [sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/) - очень мощный и достаточно простой в настройке поисковый движок, единственный известный мне понимающий русскую морфологию.

Comment: т.е. это готовый инструмент и его нужно просто встроить в код сайта?

Comment: Да, именно так.